# Como ordenar um grupo na consulta mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by, order-by

Eu estou tentando ordenar uma consulta no banco de dados agrupando as informações, porém esta mostrando a primeira cadastrada no banco, mas eu quero a última.

```
SELECT *
FROM base_rating AS B
JOIN historico_rating AS H ON B.id = H.id_base_rating
JOIN escala_rating AS E ON E.id = H.id_rating_atual
WHERE H.titulo!=''
  AND E.agencia!=''
GROUP BY B.id_emissao
```

Comment: Quais os campos você quer retornar? Ordenado por qual campo?

Comment: Se você quer trazer a ultima apenas, faz um `order by coluna DESC limit 1`

Comment: Eu quero o ultimo de cada grupo(o mais recente de cada ) não o ultimo geral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embora acho que o seu SQL não roda, para sua necessidade, faz `B.id_emissao desc`.

#### SQL completo

```
select 
  * 
from
  base_rating as B 
  JOIN historico_rating as H on B.id = H.id_base_rating 
  JOIN escala_rating as E on E.id = H.id_rating_atual 
where 
  H.titulo!='' and 
  E.agencia!='' 
group by 
  B.id_emissao desc
```

#### Editado

Se quiser somente 1 registro faça como indicado pelo outros usuários, adicione `limit 1`

Comment: Como ele disse que queria o último registro apenas, teria que ter o `limit 1`, certo?

Comment: @R.Santos editado resposta e adicionado sua consideração

Comment: Esse código mostra os cadastrados primeiros eu queria o ultimo de cada grupo, ou seja os mais atualizados de cada grupo

Comment: @AlexPeçanha adicione a estrutura da tabela e alguns registro no http://sqlfiddle.com/ e passe a url que te ajudo a fazer o SQL

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee236 
nesse não deu para colocar todo o banco de dados não nao sei se as informação foram combinando mas e isso ai tenho que pegar o campo data_sumula mais atual